# Application crashes when changing page after using Xamarin.Essentials Preferences before

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hello everyone just a few words about the application :

It's a game where I have a MenuPage with 2 themes black and light, in the MenuPage I have a button that gives me access to another page where I can choose the mode for the game.
So when I launch the app I'm using Xamarin.Essentials to get preferences that the user set before, like that (these lines of code are in the constructor of MenuPage) :

```
App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColor"] = Preferences.Get("Bg", "#181818");
App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColorInvert"] = Preferences.Get("BgInvert", "White");
StartButton.Source = Preferences.Get("startButtonSource", "LightPlayButton");
MusicButton.Source = Preferences.Get("musicButtonSource", "LightSoundOnButton");
ThemeButton.Source = Preferences.Get("themeButtonSource", "DarkThemeButton");
StatButton.Source = Preferences.Get("statButtonSource", "LightStatButton");
QuitButton.Source = Preferences.Get("quitStatButtonSource", "LightQuitButton");
```

My problem :

When I try to access to a mode the application instantly crashes and the report is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". After I tried to delete the line of codes above the application worked perfectly. So I don't get why I have a crash when using Xamarin.Essentials Preferences. Thanks for your answers.

My 1st mode page code :

```
    public partial class GamePage4x4 : ContentPage
    {
        #region Variables
        ISimpleAudioPlayer buttonSound = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        private GamePageViewModel _viewModel;
        double buttonOpacity = 0.4;
        bool loop = true;
        private double OriginalOpacity = 1;
        Color principalColorInvert = (Color)App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColorInvert"];
        public static int gamePoints;
        private uint OpacityOneLenght = (uint)TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000).TotalMilliseconds;
        #endregion

        public GamePage4x4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            buttonSound.Load("buttonSound.mp3");

            _viewModel = new GamePageViewModel();
            BindingContext = _viewModel;
            MainStackLayout.Opacity = 0;
            gamePoints = 0;
            _ = FadeTransition2Async();
            StartButtonAnimation();
            ScoreLabel.Opacity = 0;
            Timer.Opacity = 0;
            CheckTheme();
        }
...
```

Null exception occurred on line:
`Color principalColorInvert = (Color)App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColorInvert"];`

Comment: use the debugger to step through the code, or uncomment one line at a time until you find the culprit.  This is fairly basic debugging

Comment: I already did it but it stops on a variables that I set in a mode before the constructor ("        Color principalColorInvert = (Color)App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColorInvert"]; ").

Comment: But the resource comes from App.Current.Resources so it is already set isn't ? And I tried to delete this line but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Where can I send pictures of my code here ? Because I have a lot of codes and it's quite hard to explain because I speak French.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info I just did it

Comment: The line '''Color principalColorInvert =(Color)App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColorInvert"];''' But even if I delete it I get the same error after. It's just when I delete de lines of my MenuPage that everything works.

Comment: I tried what you did and I don't know why in the Local pane I don't have the info of App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColorInvert"]

Comment: I didn't understand what you asked me sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245010/discussion-between-toolmakersteve-and-nico).

Comment: The stack trace should show the line # that is causing the exception

Comment: Added that to question, based on the chat discussion. See my answer for the results of that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** When using Resources in c# code (rather than only using in XAML), the automatic conversions from string to the needed type (that XAML does) are not available. One way to avoid problems is to make sure the Resource is the needed type, rather than simply a string.

---

Results of the discussion that was continued in chat.

1. The original problem occurred on this line:
   `Color principalColorInvert = (Color)App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColorInvert"];`
2. Debugging showed that the Resource key contained a `string`. The cause of that problem is that the resource is storing a **string**; that line failed to convert from `string` to `Color`. [Though I wouldn't expect a `null` exception, so there may  have also been a problem elsewhere.]
3. **One way to fix** is to explicitly create a Color when saving in Resources:

```cs
App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColor"] = ColorConverters.FromHex(Preferences.Get("Bg", "#181818"));
App.Current.Resources["PrincipalColorInvert"] = ColorConverters.FromHex(Preferences.Get("BgInvert", "#FFFFFF"));
```

4. If one has a `Xamarin.Forms.Color`, `ToHex()` can be used to create the desired string, for storing in Preferences:
   `Preferences.Set("Bg", Xamarin.Forms.Color.White.ToHex());`
5. If one has a `System.Drawing.Color`, first cast to XF color, to make use of that converter:

```cs
    System.Drawing.Color color = ...;
    `Preferences.Set("Bg", ((Xamarin.Forms.Color)(color)).ToHex()));
```

---

NOTE: After verifying that these fixes work, Nico was still struggling to correctly Save and Load these Preferences. They decided it was not worth trying to get this mechanism to work.

This Q&A is left here, to document a solution for accessing a Color Resource that was a string, and for Save/Load a Preference string for that Color.